# Why does wiredep keep removing my bower component?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower, bower-install, grunt-wiredep

Whenever the wiredep grunt task runs, it removes socketio.

```
~/.g/p/g/g/s/b/f/brody % git diff
diff --git a/app/app/index.html b/app/app/index.html
index 9abc970..f9dd603 100644
--- a/app/app/index.html
+++ b/app/app/index.html
@@ -65,7 +65,6 @@
     <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
     <!-- bower:js -->
     <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
-    <script src="bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
     <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
diff --git a/app/test/karma.conf.js b/app/test/karma.conf.js
index 710f26a..ab51cc6 100644
--- a/app/test/karma.conf.js
+++ b/app/test/karma.conf.js
@@ -20,7 +20,6 @@ module.exports = function(config) {
     files: [
       // bower:js
       'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
-      'bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js',
       'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
       'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
       'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
~/.g/p/g/g/s/b/f/brody %
```

I have had socketio installed via

```
bower install socket.io-client --save
```

And the package is in my `bower.json`

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io-client": "~1.3.4",
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-aria": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-messages": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-socket-io": "~0.7.0",
    "message-center": "https://github.com/mateu-aguilo-bosch/message-center.git#~1.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "appApp"
}
```

When I run `bower install` nothing changes.

The app builds fine on my mac, but for some crazy reason, it keeps removing socketio and fails to build on my ubuntu machine.

Comment: From what I can tell, the actual package name in bower is `sio-client`. So try `"sio-client": "~1.3.4"` (My bower search: http://bower.io/search/?q=socket.io-client )

Comment: Great, I'll move it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Searching for `socket.io-client` on bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=socket.io-client) produces a package named `sio-client`, but nothing named `socket.io-client`.

Try:

```
"sio-client": "~1.3.4"
```

in your bower.json and it should straighten out.

Comment: What boggles my mind is, why the hell does 'socket.io-client' work on my mac. Maybe the package used to exist but got renamed or something.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering the same thing, and arrived at the same guess. :)